# Thoughts on Wordpress database design

Tags: mysql, database

I am beginning to work on a database design for a user generated content site and am trying to think of the best approach.  I will have groups, topics, and topic replies in my set-up.  I am wondering if it is better to design the database to store all of this information in a generic content table, similar to Wordpress, and store corresponding actions (bookmarking a topic, etc) in an actions table.

I have been reading a lot and there seems to be a divide between using this method versus creating a separate content and action table for each type (group, topic, topic reply).

I am curious to know what your opinion is.  It will be a SaaS solution and a solid amount of topic and topic replies will be made each day.

Having separate tables means more JOINs, but the tables won't grow so big, so quickly, while the single content and action table will grow very quickly, but won't require as many joins.

Thoughts?  Opinions?  It will be a MySQL database FYI.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably have multiple entities in an object oriented approach using an orm like for example doctrine to persist them. That will do a lot of stuff for you. That desicion btw realy depends on how you define your types and what they will have in common. It is hardly possible to give you a good advise.

Doctrine ORM:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/orm.html